# White space above the webpart in a library page when enabling "Metadata Navigation"

Tags: document-library, navigation, metadata

I have created a new library. It works fine. I enabled the "Metadata Navigation" and now I see alot of white space above my library. See printscreen. How can I reduce this white space? When I disable "Metadata Navigation" the white space is gone.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot with better resolution?

Comment: Yea, maybe trim the screenshot. The 80% white is not really all that useful. Zoom in on the problem instead. If you don't maximize the window, you may get a better shot. Have you manipulated the CSS? Looks like the web part and the nav are not floating, but placed underneath each other. That can happen with wrongly applied CSS

Comment: I updated my printscreen. The zoom is now 100 %.

Comment: I still have the same issue guys?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a content editor webpart. In this webpart I refer to a custom css file. Inside this css I have set the width.